Given $f(z)=exp((1+z)/(z-1)$, prove $f(z) \in H^{\infty} (\mathbb{D})$.
Im a physics student trying to figure out some issues about complex analysis. I have been defined the group
$H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$={ f is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ / $||f||_{\infty}\leq \infty, \forall z \in \mathbb{D}$}
Since $f(z)=exp((1+z)/(z-1))$ is a combination of holomorphic functions, the first condition is not that big of a deal. However, im struggling trying to figure out how to prove $||f||_\infty \leq \infty, \forall z \in \mathbb{D}$. I would be very grateful if someone could give me a hint.
Thanks in advance and let me know if I should add something else to the information. I'll keep trying.

You have to show that the real part of $(1+z)/(z-1)$ is bounded above. What is the image of the unit disk under $z \mapsto (1+z)/(z-1)$?

Oh, I've concluded that the transformation makes a correlation between the unitary disk (im considering $\mathbb{D}=z \in \mathbb{C} / |z|<1$) and the left half plane. Therefore, I can have an upper bound of M(z)=(1+z)/(z-1) as M(-1)=0 and keep going with the analysis. Thanks a lot! I'll update the post as soon as posible

Please put the richt bracket somewhere, otherwise you formula is ambiguous...

@Iván Sorry to be nitpicky. The condition $\forall z \in \mathbb{D}$ is redundant because $\lVert f \rVert_{\infty}$ does not depend on $z$.
